# Can I apply Vitali-Porter at a single point set $A=\{z_0\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

**The Vitali-Poter theorem says** that given a domain $Ω$ and a set $A⊂Ω$, with $A$ having an accumulation point at $Ω$. If we have a sequence $\{f_n\}∈\mathcal{H}(Ω)$, with $f_n$ uniformly bounded over compacts in $Ω$, such that $∀a∈A$ there exists $\lim_{n \to ∞}f_n(a) ∈ ℂ$; then:

$$f_n \text{ converges uniformly over compacts}$$

---

**My question:** Can I apply the theorem to a set $A=\{z_0\}$?

Comment: Does $\{z_0\}$ have an accumulation point? What's the _definition_ of "accumulation point" anyway?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich an accumulation point is a limit point. And $z_0$ is a limit point at $Ω$, because for every neighborhood of $z_0$, it contains a point of $Ω$ different to $z_0$.

Comment: There's no such thing as "accumulation point at $\Omega$". Not to complain about the English, but maybe it's part of the problem. The question is whether $A=\{z_0\}$ has an accumulation point in $\Omega$. That is, does there exist $z\in\Omega$ such that every neighborhood of $z$ contains a point of $A$ other than $z$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich but we must have a limit point at $Ω$, not at $A$. Then what the neighborhood needs to contain, is a point of $Ω$ different to $z_0$, not a point in $A$ different to $z_0$ itself (which of course is not posible).

Comment: You really have to stop talking a limit point "at" $\Omega$ or "at" $A$. In your last comment it sounded like you're talking about the condition "$z_0$ is a limit point of $\Omega$". That's irrelevant - the condition is "$A$ has an accumulation point in $\Omega$". Which means what I said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. The expression "A having an accumulation point at $\Omega$" means that $A$ has an accumulation point that belongs to $\Omega$ and not to $\partial\Omega$. In other words, there exists a sequence $z_n\in A,$ $z_n\neq z_m$, for $n\neq m$, which converges to a $z_0\in \Omega$. Thus, $A$ must be an infinite set.

Comment: I think that since the limit point has to be at $Ω$, the sequence $\{z_n\}$ can be outside $A$, because it just needs to satisfy that the limit of that sequence is a point in $A$.

Comment: But the set $A$ has an accumulation point. The sequence must be in $A$. Do you know what an accumulation point of a set means?

Comment: maybe I'm wrong, but if $A$ has an accumulation point at $Ω$, by definition it is because there is a point $z_0∈A$, satisfying that for every neighborhood of $z_0$ in $Ω$ (for example $\mathbb{D}(z_0,r)⊂Ω$), it contains a point $ω∈Ω$ with $ω≠z_0$.

Comment: The point $\omega$ you wrote must belong to $A$. Otherwise what's the point of such a definition.

Comment: not necessarily, take $A=\{x∈ℝ:\ 0<x<2\}$ and $Ω=\{z=x+iy:\ 0<x<2,\ -1<y<1\}$. Then we have that $z_0=1$ is an accumulation point at $Ω$, since for every $\mathbb{D}(1,r)$ (with $r < 1$), we have that each disk contains a point of $Ω$.

Comment: And why does this prove that I am wrong? Just google ''accumulation point of a set''.

Comment: because in that case if you take $ω=1+\frac{r}{2}i$, it doesn't belong to $A$, it belongs to $Ω$.

Comment: So does there exist a sequence in $A$ that converges to $1$? I do not say that every sequence that converges to $1$ must belong to $A$, but that there exists such a sequence.

Comment: but the statement of the theorem says that the accumulation point that is contained in $A$ must be an accumulation point in $Ω$, not that it must be an accumulation point in $A$

Comment: No the statement of the theorem is that the set $A$ has an accumulation point that belongs to $\Omega$.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks for being so patient! :)